# What is the appropriate response to "Your Chinese is so good!"

Tags: simplified-characters

A lot of the time, Chinese people will respond to a foreigner speaking Chinese with "wow your Chinese is so good!" What is a polite way to respond without sounding rude or full of yourself? Especially when you have studied Chinese for multiple years and you would like to just have a normal conversation.

Comment: standard phrase: ：不敢当!
jukuu：You flatter me. 你过奖了。你太捧我啦。6.  You flatter me. I wish I could deserve such compliments. 好说！好说！ 您太夸奖了。

Comment: user6065's comment is a lot better than answers below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

是嗎？ (or 有嗎？ or 真的嗎？) 我覺得沒有很好吔。
Really? I do not think it's very good.
Really? I don't think my Chinese is very good.

or

沒有啦！謝謝你。
No. Thank you.
Not at all. Thank you.

You don't have to worry about this.
It's just like somebody asks a foreigner, "Where are you from?".

Answer (score 4):

There are many good suggestions in the answers, for example:

> user6065 wrote:
>
> *standard phrase: ：不敢当! jukuu：You flatter me. 你过奖了。你太捧我啦。6. You flatter me. I wish I could deserve such compliments. 好说！好说！ 您太夸奖了。*

But a slight drawback of using standard phrases is it makes you sound a little bit too formal and distant. If your Chinese is actually great, it would make your modest sounds false.

> you would like to just have a normal conversation.

It can be done by simply say "謝謝"(thanks) or "过奖" (it is too high a praise)--  A short reply without too much emphasis. Then go on with the conversation.

> [Phrases to brush off compliments](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?1,136311,136326#msg-136326)
>
> A humble response should be brief and low key.
>   Long phrase felt more like a speech.
>
> [Use of 過獎](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?1,134810,134854#msg-134854)
>
> 過獎 =太過/過於( too much / overly) 褒獎 / 誇獎 ( greatly praise / overly praise)
>   Usually, you use 過獎 as a polite/ humble respond to a great compliment

Answer (score 3):

The polite Chinese response to flattering comments is to deny them.  哪裏哪裏 (approximately: “'good', where?”) is a common phrase that can be used, or 不好 “not good”, or 還差得遠了 “far from it”, or 還要多學 “I have to study more”.  A more literate phrase is 見笑 ("[people] laugh at [my skills]").

Answer (score 2):

You can say，真的吗？我的中文能得到一个中国人的表扬，太棒了！ really？ it is awesome that my chinese gets complimented by a chinese！
he or she will be flattered.

Answer (score 1):

1 - If you say "谢谢", people will think you are rather proud
2 - If you say long sentences like: "真的吗？我的中文能得到一个中国人的表扬，太棒了！" people won't even listen until the end of such a long answer and will mainly think you are trying to show off and boast...
3 - Whatever the answer, it is not because you get a smile in return that people won't think u're rather arrogant. West and East react differently aka 直接 (zhíjiē) and 间接 (jiànjiē)

So what should you say then? 
Just: "哪里哪里!" is the simplest and the BEST option as it is exactly what the (Chinese) person who praised u is expecting you to answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

One common answer is “哪里哪里” which literally translates to "Where? Where?" But it is kind of a coy way to humbly accept the compliment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know answers are well-meant, but I do not particularly recommend false modesty. If I were you (or as I am speaking as a L2 learner), I would probably say something like: "謝謝啦！口說還行，才學了一兩年。" (revise to fit your case) Or if you *really* want to show an air of modesty, consider: "您客氣了。中文博大精深，還要加強呢！"

Answer (score -1):

I like the "you flatter me" response but since I just learned the phrase here I say 不太好。It seems to work.  And it's true!